# Select element following element containing string in XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

If a `ch_title` paragraph contains a word that I'm searching, I want scrapy to select the associated `ch_spec` paragraph:

```
<div class="holder-specificatii">

  <div class="box-specificatie" id="specifications-93-">
    <div class="ch_group"></div>

    <p class="ch_title">IPhone:</p>
    <p class="ch_spec">iPhone 6</p>
    <p class="ch_title">Tip Telefon:</p>
    <p class="ch_spec">Smartphone</p>
    <p class="ch_title">Sloturi Sim:</p>
    <p class="ch_spec">Single Sim</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a `ch_title` `p` that contains (for example) `"Tip"` and you want to select the next following `ch_spec` `p`, use this XPath:

```
//p[@class='ch_title'][contains(.,'Tip')]/following-sibling::p[@class='ch_spec'][1]
```

to return:

```
<p class="ch_spec">Smartphone</p>
```